# How to disable SVC ARM instruction (gcc, uclibc, buildroot)?

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, buildroot, uclibc

I'm using buildroot.
Compilation works fine, but binaries on target system says "Illegal instruction"

I have used strace:

> execve("/opt/busybox", ["/opt/busybox"], [/* 8 vars */]) = 0 brk(0)
>   = 0
>   --- SIGILL {si_signo=SIGILL, si_code=ILL_ILLTRP, si_addr=0xa3f20} ---
>   +++ killed by SIGILL +++ Illegal instruction

and then IDA.

The reason is SVC instruction (si_addr pointed to it in all binaries i tried)

What should i do to prevent using this instruction by GCC ?

Comment: That's the `SuperVisor Call`, used for making system calls - you will need it. Problem might be then a mismatch between kernel and what you are trying to build.

Comment: Yes. Kernel already compiled and installed. I can't change it now :( also i dont have sources/configuration from exesting kernel.

Comment: I retagged Linux (not SVC) that is some Microsoft web server thing and I tried to [update the wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1590553).  I would investigate *EABI* versus *OABI*, this changes the `SVC/SWI` calling interface. See [trap.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/traps.c)  You can boot with `user_debug=0xff` in the kernel *command line*.

Comment: So, EABI is SVC and OABI is SWI ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like i have solved this problem.

The reason is EABI / OABI misconfiguration. Thanks to **artless noise**!
I need OABI configuration.

Also, i really dont know why, but it start work only on GCC 4.3.x On default buildroot configuration of gcc 4.7.x eabi/oabi has no effect.

Finnaly, i set additional GCC options:

> --with-march=armv5te --with-cpu=arm926ej-s --with-mtune=arm926ej-s --enable-multilib --disable-libssp --enable-languages=c,c++

Comment: OABI is deprecated, you should really build your kernel with EABI support instead, and build all your userspace EABI.